# Firebase Realtime Database Websocket Exception Error while creating Secure Socket

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

On Startup it works fine but after sometime it gives websocket error exception for realtime database with also cannot verify hostname.

> D/WebSocket: ws_87 - closing itself
>   D/Connection: conn_87 - Realtime connection failed
>   D/Connection: conn_87 - closing realtime connection
>   D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
>   D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
>   D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 8773ms
>   D/WebSocket: ws_87 - closed
>   D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
>   D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
>   D/Connection: conn_88 - Opening a connection
>   D/WebSocket: ws_88 - WebSocket error.
>       com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketException: error while creating secure socket to wss://s-example.firebaseio.com/.ws?ns=fir-example
>           at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.createSocket(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:332)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:358)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:143)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
>        Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Cannot verify hostname: s-example.firebaseio.com
>           at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:205)
>           at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:537)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.createSocket(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:318)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:358) 
>           at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47) 
>           at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:143) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760) 
>   D/WebSocket: ws_88 - closing itself
>   D/Connection: conn_88 - Realtime connection failed
>   D/Connection: conn_88 - closing realtime connection
>   D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
>   D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
>   D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 13647ms
>   D/WebSocket: ws_88 - closed